Domain decomposition chunks: Verification passes on 1 GPU but fails on 2 GPUs
I am using OpenMP, C++, icpx, on Intel Developer Cloud's 4x GPU Max 1100 + Xeon
CPU code:
double rsd[ISIZ3][ISIZ2/2*2+1][ISIZ1/2*2+1][5];
double frct[ISIZ3][ISIZ2/2*2+1][ISIZ1/2*2+1][5];
double rho_i[ISIZ3][ISIZ2/2*2+1][ISIZ1/2*2+1];
double qs[ISIZ3][ISIZ2/2*2+1][ISIZ1/2*2+1];
double u[ISIZ3][ISIZ2/2*2+1][ISIZ1/2*2+1][5];

#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for(k=0; k<nz; k++){
    for(j=0; j<ny; j++){            
        for(i=0; i<nx; i++){
            for(m=0; m<5; m++){
                rsd[k][j][i][m]=-frct[k][j][i][m];
            }
            tmp=1.0/u[k][j][i][0];
            rho_i[k][j][i]=tmp;
            qs[k][j][i]=0.50*(u[k][j][i][1]*u[k][j][i][1]
                    +u[k][j][i][2]*u[k][j][i][2]
                    +u[k][j][i][3]*u[k][j][i][3])
                *tmp;
        }
    }
}

GPU code (scheme):
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for device(device_id) 
for (k = first_index; k < next_index; k++){
    for(j=0; j<ny; j++){            
        for(i=0; i<nx; i++){
            for(m=0; m<5; m++){
                rsd[k][j][i][m]=-frct[k][j][i][m];
            }
            tmp=1.0/u[k][j][i][0];
            rho_i[k][j][i]=tmp;
            qs[k][j][i]=0.50*(u[k][j][i][1]*u[k][j][i][1]
                    +u[k][j][i][2]*u[k][j][i][2]
                    +u[k][j][i][3]*u[k][j][i][3])
                *tmp;
        }
    }
}

Its successfully offloaded to one device (verification of the whole computation is still successful),
but unsuccessful with 2 GPUs (even though other similar parts of the code does work on multiple GPUs).
In the profiler I do see activity on both GPUs, but the results of the computation are wrong for some reason.
Above code** I use correctly device enter/exit data mapping. I will provide here just an example of it:
#pragma omp target enter data map(to: u[first_index:chunk_size_final][0:ISIZ2/2*2+1][0:ISIZ1/2*2+1][0:5]) device(device_id)

For 2 GPUs, I use the domain decomposition method (divide the k loop into 2 chunks), using k_start and k_stop.
Exactly what is happening is:

Above the code**, I got omp parallel which spawns 2 CPU threads. I use the same number of CPU threads and GPUs (e.g. 2).
When those 2 CPU threads reach code**, I assign device_id for each CPU thread, and perform the offload task on half of the k iterations' space on each.

Notes:

Other than the next reference, I haven't found any complete example for similar use case:
https://pawseysc.github.io/sc20-gpu-offloading/07-multi-gpu/index.html
The data mapping to chunks is done correctly, proof to that is the other similar code parts that does work with 2-4 GPUs.
Also just in case, I put a barrier before and after code**.
In my case ISIZ3=ISIZ2=ISIZ1 is equal to 4 main problem sizes I'm testing (64 x 64 x 64 or 102 x 102 x 102 or 162 x 162 x 162 or 408 x 408 x 408).
Compiler flags:
icpx -std=c++14 -Ofast -qopenmp -fopenmp-targets=spir64 -xSAPPHIRERAPIDS -ipo -g -gline-tables-only -fdebug-info-for-profiling


Env variables: OMP_TARGET_OFFLOAD=MANDATORY, OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 (which I set the same also the matching variable of number of GPUs to be 2).


Any suggestions what can go wrong here, please? Did I miss something?

Your question is about a GPU issue but you provided a CPU code. What is your GPU implementation? OpenMP cannot auto-magically transform a CPU implementation (the one provided) to a GPU one. Besides, the CPU implementation is incomplete. We have to guess you did things properly which is a problem to answer the question correctly. For example, the #pragma omp parallel is missing. Not to mention all the declaration of the variables (so we do not even know their type).

Even with a correct GPU implementation, this code is not GPU-friendly so it will likely be slow (possibly slower than a good CPU implementation). Nvidia/AMD GPUs operates on SIMD registers of at least 32 items and they need to be stored contiguously to be efficiently loaded/stored (otherwise, it is typically serialized).

Put it shortly : please provide a minimal reproducible example (which includes a minimal complete code, the compiler used and the compilers flags, possibly the target GPU) and please see how GPUs works to write an efficient implementation fully using the available resources, rather than wasting even more resources.

Thanks @JérômeRichard for answering, I provided now the missing info.
Can you elaborate why it is likely to be not " GPU-friendly" please. Or how can i modify it to be more suitable

You should not use omp parallel before omp target. The first tell OpenMP to create threads on the CPU. The later to run some (parallel) code on the device. In practice, GPUs kernels are always parallel and there is no need for multiple threads to spawn kernels on the GPU (at least not for 1 GPU in 99% of the use-cases). It can actually often makes things slower (and bogus) to spawn multiple threads doing that.

AFAIK, with device(device_id) you tell OpenMP to run the code on the device device_id so it is run on 1 GPU only. If you want to run on multiple GPU, you can for example run the loops multiple times with a different device_id. This part can be done using multiple threads (as opposed as for 1 GPU). IDK if OpenMP can execute a kernel on multiple GPUs but I guess no. With this solution, you need to partition your work so the 2 GPUs compute different things. For example by splitting the nz loop in 2 parts like you did.

If you do not use multiple threads, I wonder if OpenMP waits at the end of the omp target code. This is certainly the case. If so, using threads is critical for multiple GPU. Alternatively, I think you can use the nowait clause to avoid OpenMP waiting at the end of the omp target code, but then a synchronization is certainly needed after that. My knowledge on this part of OpenMP is limited but I hope this helps.

Regarding the not "GPU-friendly", it is because Nvidia GPU execute codes using SIMD units of typically 32 items called warp. Generally, 2 warps are executed simultaneously so you need a SIMD-friendly code which can be vectorized to run on 64 items. If there is not enough parallelism, then only a fraction of the warp will be used massively decreasing performance. Besides, GPU needs to read/write items consecutively for good performance. Otherwise, accesses can be serialized (much slower). Note AMD/Intel use a different architecture and terminology, hence my comment about specifying that.

On top of that GPUs are massively parallel so you need enough parallel work for the >1000 SIMD units to operate in parallel (+ at least >4x that for the GPU to hide the latency properly). In your code, I think the work is only distributed on the k loop so there is a small chance for nz to be large enough. Even if it is, memory accesses will be very inefficient serializing a lot of operations (and so resulting in bad performance). Based on this code, using multiple GPU will be useless since it reduce even more the amount of parallelism of each GPU which should already not be enough.

The amount of parallelism of a Nvidia GPU can be quantified with the number of "CUDA core" which is for example 14_592 on a H100 GPU. If you only use 1000 of them, then the execution time will likely be 14 times higher. This is a simplified explanation since GPU are very complex. In practice, you often need the number of CUDA threads to be much more than that. For example, on my GPU with 1408 CUDA core, 6000 CUDA threads is often not enough. Thus, on modern GPU servers, you certainly need hundreds of CUDA cores for the computation not to be inefficient, especially with multiple GPUs.

It is not clear what the specification of the "GPU Max" are but it looks like it is Intel GPU and more specifically the "Intel Data Center GPU Max 1100" and "[...] 1550". They have respectively 7168 and 16384 "shading cores" (equivalent of CUDA cores). They have 8 "vector engines" per core and it looks like each vector engine have 16 SIMD lanes (as opposed to 32). Thus, I think the last comment also applies to Intel GPUs like the one you use. I advise you to use Intel profiling tools to check the occupancy.
